Wifi driver rtl8821 no longer works after kernel update
as my wifi card doesn't yet have a Debian12 driver, I use a wifi adapter: TP-Link AC600 T2U Nano. As long as I boot with kernel 6.1.0-25, everything works fine with the rtl8821cu driver installed. The problem appeared after an update to kernel 6.1.0-26: the adapter is detected but doesn't work.
$ lsusb
.......
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:011e TP-Link AC600 wireless Realtek RTL8811AU [Archer T2U Nano]

$ lsmod | grep 8821
8821cu               3162112  0   --> module is loaded but not used
cfg80211             1347584  1 8821cu
usbcore               401408  9 xhci_hcd,usbnet,usbhid,8821cu,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci,cdc_ether,hid_logitech_hidpp

# dkms status 
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.4, 6.10.11+bpo-amd64, x86_64: installed
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.4, 6.1.0-26-amd64, x86_64: installed

What I tried:

boot with a newer kernel from the backports repository: = 6.10
reinstall rtl8821cu driver
install realtek non-free-firmware from trixie (testing)

What I'd like to know is if there's anything else I can try or if it's hopeless and I have to wait for a new update that will hopefully solve the problem.

You need to review the syslog (e.g. the dmesg command) for any/all messages related to the wifi device driver. You're only looking at the final state or outcome of boot. Whereas the syslog is the record of what happened and any error messages.

I should have mentioned it, but I looked at the boot logs: [dmesg -l (err,warn), dmesg | grep -i (8821,wifi,wlan,fail,err)] and I didn't see anything related to the problem.

I changed the driver to 8821au and it  works fine now, with both kernels. It's my fault, I should have stuck to what the lsusb command recommended as a driver
